# How to remove a space at the end of word in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that works well to create folders based off of two columns, but for some reason it's crapping out with a folder that has a space at the end of it.

Here is the code:

```
Dim baseFolder As String, newFolder As String
    lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    wsJL.Range("S2:U2").Copy wsJL.Range("S3:U" & lastrow)
    Range("J3:M" & lastrow).Calculate
    Range("S3:U" & lastrow).Calculate
    baseFolder = wbBK1.path & Application.PathSeparator & "Photos" & Application.PathSeparator
     'folders will be created within this folder - Change to sheet of your like.

    If Right(baseFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
     baseFolder = baseFolder & Application.PathSeparator

       For Each cell In Range("S3:S" & lastrow)   'CHANGE TO SUIT

           'Company folder - column S

           newFolder = baseFolder & cell.Value
           If Len(Dir(newFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir newFolder

           'Part number subfolder - column T

           newFolder = newFolder & Application.PathSeparator & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
           If Len(Dir(newFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir newFolder

       Next

        End With
```

Now where it's getting caught up is at this one:

`"The Richmond Group "` the reason I think is because it has a space at the end of the title, and that doesn't translate to a space when creating a folder.

Now I have in S and T is this:

**S**

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C2,",","")," "," "),".",""),"/","-"),"""",""),"*","")`

**T**

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D2,",","")," "," "),".",""),"/","-"),"""",""),"*","")`

Now with that being said, I can't figure out a way to remove the end space at the end of the name.

If someone can help there it be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Just wrap the string in `Trim( ... )`

Comment: Make it into an answer, and I'll give you credit, I thought of that just after I posted the question.  My guess is the reason I didn't see it outright was I'm fighting a cold.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Trim function:

> Dim LResult As String
>
> LResult = Trim ("   Alphabet   ")

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php

Answer (score 3):

Use `Trim$`.

It is a string function which means it is more efficient than it's variant cousin `Trim`

A very useful reference [No variants please](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#variant)